# How to improve the performance of this select query?

Tags: performance, oracle-10g, select

I have two tables: TABLE1 and TABLE2.

And I am running this `select` query to fetch the data. It takes long time to run:

```
SELECT TABLE1.* , TABLE2.COL1 , TABLE2.COL4 FROM TABLE1, TABLE2     
WHERE TABLE1.COL1 IN ('1','TEXT','HO TED')     
  AND TABLE1.COL2= 1800
  AND TABLE2.COL1 = 10519198     
  AND TABLE1.COL3>= 100
  AND TABLE1.COL4= TABLE2.COL2
  AND TABLE2.COL3=('TEXT')
```

How could I improve the performance of this select query? Does too many `AND` affect my performance?

Comment: What indexes do you have? What's the explain plan?

Comment: @Mat No i dont have any indexes

Comment: This is the solution. You should use indices. What type of them, and how, it depends on the distribution of your tables.

Comment: @PeterHorvath Any common rules to create the index ? or things i should keep in mind while creating a index

Comment: @sankrish Yes, there are a lot, but it depends really on the exact size and data distribution of your tables. This is because you didn't get a good answer until now - simply you didn't said the needed informations to it. Maybe a "how to index complex queries tutorial" or such search on google...

Comment: @PeterHorvath thanks for your help . Actually i found that i have an index for the col 1 for table 1 . Now i should consider index for table 2 .

Comment: @PeterHorvath does that `and` clause creates any performance issue . Any idea of using `joins` here

Comment: No, first you should extend the TABLE1(COL1) index to the columns COL2 and COL3, and assert that it is a tree-based index.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your comments, here is a maybe faster version:

```
SELECT TABLE1.* , TABLE2.COL1 , TABLE2.COL4
FROM TABLE1
INNER JOIN TABLE2 ON TABLE1.COL4 = TABLE2.COL2
WHERE TABLE1.COL1 IN ('1','TEXT','HO TED')     
  AND TABLE1.COL2=1800
  AND TABLE1.COL3>=100
  AND TABLE2.COL1=10519198     
  AND TABLE2.COL3=('TEXT')
```

And you need to create a tree-index on `TABLE1(COL2, COL1, COL3)`. Beware: hash-based index weren't o.k, because of your condition of `TABLE1.COL3>=100` is an interval-query, which is impossible to be fastened by hash-based indices! This is also the cause, why must be COL3 the last element of the `TABLE1(COL2, COL1, COL3)` index.

Another index which can make things better were a hash-based index on `TABLE2(COL1,COL3)`.

Further indices which will probably help: `TABLE1(COL4)` and `TABLE2(COL2)` (both).

None of the indices should be unique.

Comment: I would first try an index on table1 where `col2` is the leading column. As a rule of thumb, columns used with an equality operator should go first. The `OR` condition for `col1` won't probably benefit very much from the index.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name It is not an OR, it is a lookup in a (quite small, and fixed constant) set. The sql optimizer can probably handle this, but I optimize the query for the case if it couldn't.

Comment: @PeterHorvath `col1 IN ('1','TEXT','HO TED')` is equivalent to `(col1='1' OR col1='TEXT' OR col1='HO TED')`

Comment: @ypercube Yes, it is equivalent, but can (and surely will) be implemented with a set intersection search and not with different, separate queries.

Comment: @PeterHorvath please explain about `interval-query` and also why you are preferring for `tree-index ` for table 1

Comment: @sankrish I suggest to do a little bit of googling or a new question. Tree-index: because altough it is a little bit slower, it can index queries for intervals (also with the `<`, `>`, `>=`, `<=` operators) as well.